# Parsing XML in Python with Loop

Tags: python, xml, loops, python-3.x, elementtree

I am new to Python.

I have a piece of python I have written to take out a data element I need from an XML that I have. The problem is I do not know how to repeat it to get out all the elements that I need.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import lxml.etree


doc = lxml.etree.parse('datafiles.xml')
total_datasets = doc.xpath('count//driversUsed)')


tree = ET.parse('datafiles.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

alias = root[1]
dataset = alias[0]
current = dataset[0]

print(current.text)
```

So right now the current has the first value that I need but I need to do a loop where dataset = alias[1], dataset = alias[2] .... dataset = alias[total_datasets].

I've done a little bit of looping but I don't know how to do it where the variable is not just an integer but has the [] with the integer inside.

Comment: What do you mean take out a data element? Are you trying to create a new XML or extract data from existing XML?

Comment: I think `import lxml.etree` can do work whatever you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for` and you don't need `total_datasets`

```
for dataset in alias:
    current = dataset[0]
    print(current.text)
```

It is basic knowledge so better find some Python Tutorial.